# Bulk upload user using JSON file to Azure B2C active directory in Java

Tags: java, json, object, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I connected my java code to the Azure B2C active directory and used

```
User user = graphClient.users("611us0f2a-7608-4edd-8c4c-7871d8e70b8e").buildRequest().get();
```

I got result in get() request which mean my connection is correct, now I wan to bulk upload users that are existing in my local db, I created a JSON format file which (user_data.json), it looks like this -

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "displayName": "Amanda Polly",
      "givenName": "Amanda",
      "surname": "Polly",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "emailAddress",
          "issuerAssignedId": "amandapolly@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "PST",
      "extension_locale": "en-US",
      "extension_tenant": "EG1234"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Lowa Doe",
      "givenName": "Lowa",
      "surname": "Doe",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "userName",
          "issuerAssignedId": "lowadow123"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "PST",
      "extension_locale": "en-US",
      "extension_tenant": "EG1234"
    }
   ]
}
```

Here in the JSON, I have a wrapper "users" and then followed by all the users (2 users as of now if you see in JSON), so now I have to create them using mircosoft graph api, how do I proceed? what i know, i have to covert each of the user into an object and the use post() to send to create them in the directory.

Please suggest a solution for how to do it.

||For you to read Allen, as you suggested, when the code is coming to,

```
private static void updateExtension(String userID, IGraphServiceClient graphClient) 
    {
        User extensionForUser = new User();
        extensionForUser.additionalDataManager().put("extension_dfa4f1a9a2f94cd1bf8826c50d4d0464_user_type", new JsonPrimitive(extension_user_type));
        extensionForUser.additionalDataManager().put("extension_dfa4f1a9a2f94cd1bf8826c50d4d0464_timezone", new JsonPrimitive(extension_timezone));
        extensionForUser.additionalDataManager().put("extension_dfa4f1a9a2f94cd1bf8826c50d4d0464_extension_locale", new JsonPrimitive(extension_locale));
        extensionForUser.additionalDataManager().put("extension_dfa4f1a9a2f94cd1bf8826c50d4d0464_tenant", new JsonPrimitive(extension_tenant));
        graphClient.users(userID)
                .buildRequest()
                .patch(extensionForUser);
        
    }
```

It is breaking at .patch(extensionForUser) --> with error like

```
Error message: Resource 'null' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present.

PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/null
SdkVersion : graph-java/v1.9.0
Authorization : Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub25jZSI[...]
{"extension_dfa4f1a9a2f94cd1bf8826c50d4d0464_tenan[...]

404 : Not Found
[...]
```

But when I checked my Azure Directory, the user was created. Because when i re ran the code, it said a user already exist with same principal name.

Also since it is breaking in the first iteration, users to be created behind this are not getting created.

Update 2 :
[image]

[image]

Update 3 : Explanation to what I tried.

```
userID = userCreateCall(displayName, givenName, surname, extension_user_type, extension_timezone, extension_locale, extension_tenant, signInType, issuerAssignedId, graphClient);
                System.out.println(userID);
                updateExtension(userID, graphClient, extension_user_type, extension_timezone, extension_locale, extension_tenant);
```

If you see I have a for loop that will iterate through every user and in every iteration, it will pick [displayName, givenName, surname, extension_user_type, extension_timezone, extension_locale, extension_tenant, signInType, issuerAssignedId] for each user and pass it as a parameter to **userCreateCall()** method as you can see in above code, I am also passing graphClient within the param.

This is my **userCreateCall()** method,

```
User createNewUser = new User();
        createNewUser.displayName = displayName;
        createNewUser.givenName = givenName;
        createNewUser.surname = surname;
        
        LinkedList<ObjectIdentity> identitiesList = new LinkedList<ObjectIdentity>();
        ObjectIdentity identities = new ObjectIdentity();
        identities.signInType = signInType;
        identities.issuerAssignedId = issuerAssignedId;
        identities.issuer = "demoUserEngine.onmicrosoft.com";
        identitiesList.add(identities);
        
        createNewUser.identities = identitiesList;
        
        PasswordProfile passwordProfile = new PasswordProfile();
        passwordProfile.password = "passwordPASSWORD!";
        passwordProfile.forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false;
        
        createNewUser.passwordProfile = passwordProfile;
        createNewUser.passwordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration";
        
        User buildUserRequest = graphClient.users()
                                .buildRequest()
                                .post(createNewUser);
        
        
        return createNewUser.id;
```

I am returning createNewUser.id but I think it is coming NULL here, hence

```
userID = userCreateCall(displayName, givenName, surname, extension_user_type, extension_timezone, extension_locale, extension_tenant, signInType, issuerAssignedId, graphClient);
System.out.println(userID); // THIS IS giving NULL
```

So when calling update `updateExtension` userID is going as NULL,

I commented the updateExtension method so that I wont have to use **userID** and code did not break, no exception in user creation, just the userID is coming NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create the user in Azure B2C with your extension attributes directly.

We should create the user with the normal attributes first and then update the extension attributes for the user.

First of all you need to create the extension attributes (`extension_user_type`, `extension_timezone`, `extension_locale`, `extension_tenant`) in Azure Portal by following [Create a custom attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes#create-a-custom-attribute). Please note you just enter `user_type`, `timezone`, `locale`, `tenant` as the name of the extension attribute.

Then it will generate the extension attribute with the format: `extension_ApplicationClientID_attributename`, where the ApplicationClientID is the Application (client) ID of the `b2c-extensions-app` application (found in **App registrations** > **All Applications** in the Azure portal).

Note that the Application (client) ID as it's represented in the extension attribute name includes no hyphens. For example, my application id of `b2c-extensions-app` application is `a554ad42-83c8-475e-a9aa-ac09a9h25c67`. But the actual extension attribute is `extension_a554ad4283c8475ea9aaac09a9h25c67_attributename`, which has removed all the `-`. See reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api#extension-properties).

Now we are preparing to create the user. Please refer to my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");
        String clientId = "3******9-5a11-4823-88de-13*******cad";
        String clientSecret = "**********************************";
        String tenant = "allentest001.onmicrosoft.com";
        ClientCredentialProvider authProvider = new ClientCredentialProvider(
                clientId,
                scopes,
                clientSecret,
                tenant,
                NationalCloud.Global);

        IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();
        String userId = createUser(graphClient);
        updateExtension(userId, graphClient);
    }

    private static String createUser(IGraphServiceClient graphClient) {
        User user = new User();
        user.displayName = "Amanda Polly";
        user.givenName = "Amanda";
        user.surname = "Polly";
        LinkedList<ObjectIdentity> identitiesList = new LinkedList<ObjectIdentity>();
        ObjectIdentity identities = new ObjectIdentity();
        identities.signInType = "emailAddress";
        identities.issuer = "allentest001.onmicrosoft.com";
        identities.issuerAssignedId = "amandapolly@gmail.com";
        identitiesList.add(identities);
        user.identities = identitiesList;
        PasswordProfile passwordProfile = new PasswordProfile();
        passwordProfile.password = "{your password here}";
        passwordProfile.forceChangePasswordNextSignIn = false;
        user.passwordProfile = passwordProfile;
        user.passwordPolicies = "DisablePasswordExpiration";

        User newUser = graphClient.users()
                .buildRequest()
                .post(user);

        return newUser.id;
    }


    private static void updateExtension(String userId, IGraphServiceClient graphClient) {
        User user = new User();
        user.additionalDataManager().put("extension_a554ad4283c8475ea9aaac09a9h25c67_user_type", new JsonPrimitive("user"));
        user.additionalDataManager().put("extension_a554ad4283c8475ea9aaac09a9h25c67_timezone", new JsonPrimitive("PST"));
        user.additionalDataManager().put("extension_a554ad4283c8475ea9aaac09a9h25c67_extension_locale", new JsonPrimitive("PST"));
        user.additionalDataManager().put("extension_a554ad4283c8475ea9aaac09a9h25c67_tenant", new JsonPrimitive("EG1234"));
        graphClient.users(userId)
                .buildRequest()
                .patch(user);
    }
```

**Please note you should set a password while creating the user.** (see details in my code)

Comment: Thanks, I will follow this approach and let you know.

Comment: Hello Allen, I have updated the answer, it is breaking. I have attached screen shot.

Comment: @sh4r4d Are you sure the `userID` exists in this line: `graphClient.users(userID).buildRequest().patch(extensionForUser);`? You can debug it.

Comment: Hi Allen, I think I found the problem, the userID is coming null when I tried to print it!

Comment: String userId = createUser(graphClient);  -> this is coming null

Comment: @sh4r4d Can you provide more code? Are you using the same code as mine?

Comment: @sh4r4d ah sorry. I think I have made a mistake in the last line in the method `createUser`. Correct it to `return newUser.id;`

Comment: okayy, lemme try, nevertheless, I updated the question "update 3" where I explained what I did.

Comment: IT WORKED! Like a charm

Comment: @sh4r4d Glad to know it:)

Comment: Life can not be easy! getting this when calling update -> The following extension properties are not available: extension_dfa4f1a9a2f94cd1bf8826c50d4d0464_tenant,extension_dfa4

Comment: I think this is because we dont have any field like this??

Comment: I was told that we have extension fields like -> extension_tenant and so on.... also <extension_<applicationID>_fieldName.... here application ID is client ID that we used in ClientCredentialProvider?

Comment: @sh4r4d See my answer. I have explain the `applicationID` in detail. You are using a wrong `applicationID`  here.

Comment: But the Application (Client) ID that I used in creating ClientCredentialProvider, I am using same client ID in extension_<cleintID>_colName, are they not same?

Comment: @sh4r4d It should be the app id of `b2c-extensions-app` application (found in App registrations > All Applications in the Azure portal). They are not the same.

Comment: okay, i will ask someone who has access to it and provide me the ID.

Comment: @sh4r4d A normal user should be able to see the ID of `b2c-extensions-app` application. Just search for "b2c-extensions-app" in **App registrations** > **All Applications**.

Comment: i went and checked, I dont have b2c-extentions-app in All Application, seems like I do not have access or something, can you please tell me -- I have a clientID that I passed as a parameter to create CleintCredentialProvider, and the one I will use with extension_cleintID(without dash)_fieldName are not same?

Comment: because both are clientID and it is working when I am creating a user but it is not working with extension_id_fieldname during patch

Comment: @sh4r4d The clientID used to create CleintCredentialProvider is from the Azure AD app you created and configured. But the clientID in extension_cleintID(without dash)_fieldName is generated by Microsoft when you create the custom claim by following https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/user-flow-custom-attributes#create-a-custom-attribute. Make sure you have created the custom claims. Then you should be able to see `b2c-extensions-app` application. If you have followed all the steps in my answer, everything should be OK.

Comment: @sh4r4d And this official docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/manage-user-accounts-graph-api#extension-properties states clearly about the clientID in extension_cleintID(without dash)_fieldName. All the links are in my original answer.

Comment: It worked, I was using wrong extension app ID, got it right and now I am able to create users successfully! Thanks to you!

Comment: Hello Allen, I was wondering, if we do not wish to create a password while creating a new user, is this possible? I ran the code after commenting the part where we were setting password, but it gave me an exception, -->  A password must be specified to create a new user.

Comment: @sh4r4d No, it's impossible. You should follow the prompts.

Comment: Hello Allen, I was using the [  User user = graphClient.users("422a535b-a60d-4e5f-833e-2789b32ca04f").buildRequest().get();   ] to know if the user is exiting in the directory, however this approach needs pre-known user ID like the one i used. Shortcoming is, I am creating new users from a database, some users are already existing in the data base, so I want to ask if I can use issuerAssignedId and use it to send a get() request so that I can skip creation of that user and iterate next user. In short, I have to use issuerAssignedId as validator, send get() call, if value returned, skip user

Comment: I can not. disabled for me, sorry, thats why I asked here

Comment: here is the question link -  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63897504/use-issuerassignedid-as-a-get-call-to-b2c-directory-to-check-if-user-exists

Comment: I have added the link, please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

To create single user at a time, you need to make call for each of your user in Java. Please refer the API doc for that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=java). But Graph SDK also supports batching. You can compose your JSON payload consisting of individual requests and make a single POST to $batch endpoint. Please refer [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/batch-requests?tabs=java) for details.

NOTE: For current limitations with JSON batching in Microsoft Graph, see [Known Issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues#json-batching).