# Use "issuerAssignedId" as a get() call to b2c directory to check if user exists. [JAVA]

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to implement get() call for checking the existing users in b2c directory, for that I am using

```
User user = graphClient.users("422a535b-a60d-4e5f-833e-2789b32ca04f").buildRequest().get();
```

This is returning the user data, however I am only able to do this because I have user_id which was issued at the time of creation of user.

```
User buildUserRequest = graphClient.users()
                                .buildRequest()
                                .post(createNewUser);

        return buildUserRequest.id;
```

I am having a bunch of users in JSON format that I am trying to migrate, the migration is working fine, JSON looking like this :

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "displayName": "Sharad Dutta",
      "givenName": "",
      "surname": "",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "emailAddress",
          "issuerAssignedId": "00bonded007@gmail.com"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "VET",
      "extension_locale": "en-GB",
      "extension_tenant": "EG12345"
    },
    {
      "displayName": "Wayne Rooney",
      "givenName": "Wayne",
      "surname": "Rooney",
      "extension_user_type": "user",
      "identities": [
        {
          "signInType": "userName",
          "issuerAssignedId": "00bonded007"
        }
      ],
      "extension_timezone": "VET",
      "extension_locale": "en-GB",
      "extension_tenant": "EG12345"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I am creating a user, as long as the issuerAssignedId is not existing in the active directory, it working fine. I want to handle a case where I am checking issuerAssignedid using get() request, if user exist in directory, skip it so that code will not break or will get out due to exception.

I can do this using try/catch but can I use issuerAssignedId in place of user_id to check if user is existing in the b2c, if yes, then skip for that user.

Comment: When you try to create the user, if `issuerAssignedId` has existed, it will show an error "Another object with the same value for property userPrincipalName already exists". Why not use try catch to capture this error and skip it in the loop.

Comment: I can, but is this the best and efficient approach or there is another way, just curious, I thought of using try/catch initially.

Comment: When filtering on the identities property, you must supply both issuer and issuerAssignedId.Please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/objectidentity?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
    LinkedList<QueryOption> requestOptions = new LinkedList<>();
    requestOptions.add(new QueryOption("$filter", "identities/any(c:c/issuerAssignedId eq '00bonded007@gmail.com' and c/issuer eq 'contoso.onmicrosoft.com')"));

    IUserCollectionPage Users = graphClient.users()
            .buildRequest(requestOptions)
            .get();
```

Please note that you should modify the `contoso.onmicrosoft.com` to your Azure B2C tenant.

Comment: I used try/catch when I was returning id for user. It worked.

Comment: @horizon Glad to know this issue is resolved. But my answer is more suitable to answer your question. Your solution is a workaround. Can you mark my answer as accepted? Thank you!

Comment: What will this return? Will IUserCollectionPage Users = NULL if no user exist and some value if user exist?

Answer (score 1):

To answer, when we send a post() request with attributes, and return

```
User buildUserRequest = null;
        try {
            buildUserRequest = graphClient.users()
                    .buildRequest()
                    .post(createNewUser);
                  
        } catch (GraphServiceException gse) {
            LOG.warn("Skipping! userPrincipalName already exists | signInType : " + signInType + " & issuerAssignedId " + issuerAssignedId);
            exitFlag = true;
            LOG.info("Setting exitFlag for existing user : " + exitFlag);
        }
        
        if (exitFlag == true) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return buildUserRequest.id;
        }
```

This will handle any unique criteria, not just issuerAssignedId.